# launch method within a coroutine vs using withContext

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say I have the following coroutine:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

}
```

If I want to switch `Dispatchers` within the above coroutine, I can do it in the following two ways: `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {}` or `launch(Dispatchers.Main) {}`.

What's the difference between the two ways of switching `Dispatchers`? Are they basically doing the same thing, but with a different syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use withContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060268/when-to-use-withcontext)

Comment: @Mark No because it doesn't explain the difference between switching contexts using `launch` vs `withContext` within a coroutine?

Comment: Setting a dispatcher in `launch` changes the  dispatcher used in the primary coroutine when you launch it. Using `withContext` lets you switch dispatchers for a section of code in the middle of a coroutine. You seem to already know this, so it's not clear what you are asking here... Note that `withContext` will suspend while `launch` will not.

Comment: `launch` runs the block in a new coroutine, `withContext` is run in the current coroutine this is the main difference when used within a `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: @TylerV @Mark These were the answers that I was looking for originally. I know you can use both to change dispatchers within the parent coroutine, I just didn't understand the difference between the two and when you would use one over the other. To sum up, `withContext` will suspend and continue in the current coroutine, but with a different dispatcher and `launch` won't suspend and launch a new coroutine instead of staying in the parent coroutine.